# Is there a way to create a Link to some html of a specific component with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So, I have a Home component where some sections take place such as contact section, about section... . And I have some other components as well, for example Login component. And I need to know if there is a way to go to a specific section of the Home component from my Login component. Thanks for your time :)

```
// Part of my header (links point to the Home component sections)

                <a href="#about">
                    About
                </a>
                <a href="#how-it-works">
                    How it works
                </a>
                <a href="#support">
                    Support
                </a>
                <a href="#contact">
                    Talk to us
                </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to components via react-router.

If you have a route like:
`<Route path="/support/:myCoolParam" exact component={Support}/>`

Then `myCoolParam` will be available as `props.match.params.myCoolParam` from within your `Support`-Component.

You should route not via anchors though ("/#support?myCoolParam=foo") but via real paths ("/support?myCoolParam=foo").